# Storage setup (moved from windows)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage

I recently moved from Windows to Ubuntu Server 22.04.
The server was installed by the VPS provider.

The Server has 2 SSD and 1 HDD.
I discovered that all 3 drives are used for two data systems.

Is it possible to remove the HDD and exchange it with another SSD without data loss?

If so, how would it be done?

Regarding storage I have really no clue and all help is appreciated.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: Do you have physical access to the machine and are you allowed to make hardware modifications on it yourself? Otherwise this is a question for the VPS provider.

Comment: @Organic Marble, I can order the change. So e.g. I can request an additional 447GiB SSD and maybe after the change I can request to remove the 6TB, as I dont need it anymore.